# How to displaying not block when small device on bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap as framework UI. This code for display some image.

```
<div class='row-fluid'>
 <div class='span3'><img 1></div>
 <div class='span3'><img 2></div>
 <div class='span3'><img 3></div>
 <div class='span3'><img 4></div>
</div>
```

But when use small device, an image use css block (there is lot of space on right, please see image below). http://www.flickr.com/photos/99955339@N06/9975583665/

How to make, this image not blocking (use same of space already), I mean if small device has 2 image on same row and smaller again has one image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap 2.x, not the recent version. In old bootstrap - they have only one grid system.

When screen goes below 768px, all span classes has `float:none;` and `width: 100%;` This makes your all images display in stack even when having a lot of space.

Here is your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/jqPUR/

You can wrap all images in one div, or span12 and all set for what you needed:

```
<div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class='span12 img-list'>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" /> 
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" /> 
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" />        
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Little CSS for better spacing:

```
.img-list img {
    margin:0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/jqPUR/2/

And if you wish to go with Bootstrap 3 - you have 4 different grid system to make the UI any way you wanted.

A simple demo using Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-4 - col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" /></div>
 <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-4 - col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" /></div>
 <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-4 - col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" /></div>
 <div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-4 - col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/160/" /></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/LPG3S/